# Kotlin - Higher Order Functions Costs?

Tags: android, function, kotlin

Is there  any  cost of Higher Order Functions?  I can  solve some  problems  with  it easily but  I am  not sure  can it  effect performance. Are there any limitations about  it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Lambdas passed to *higher-order functions* are compiled to generic `Function` objects. This approach certainly adds some costs, also due to *boxing overhead* when primitive types are involved. 
So yes, it can effect performance. You should use [`inline`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html) higher order functions whenever it makes sense because the aforementioned caveats won’t be problematic anymore.

Taken from the docs:

> Using higher-order functions imposes **certain runtime penalties**: each function is an object, and it captures a closure, i.e. those variables that are accessed in the body of the function. Memory allocations (both for function objects and classes) and virtual calls introduce runtime overhead.
>
> But it appears that in many cases this kind of **overhead can be eliminated by inlining the lambda expressions**.

There are certain restrictions for `inline` though. Read in the [docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html#public-inline-restrictions).

#### Example

**Definition of higher-order function and caller code:**

```
fun hoFun(func: (Int) -> Boolean) {
    func(1337)
}

//invoke with lambda
val mod = 2
hoFun { it % mod == 0 }
```

**Bytecode Java Representation:**

```
public static final void hoFun(@NotNull Function1 func) {
  Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull(func, "func");
  func.invoke(1337);
}

final int mod = 2;
hoFun((Function1)(new Function1() {

     public Object invoke(Object var1) {
        return this.invoke(((Number)var1).intValue());
     }

     public final boolean invoke(int it) {
        return it % mod == 0;
     }
}));
```

As mentioned, the lambda is compiled to a `Function` object. Each invocation leads to the instantiation of a new `Function`object because the `mod` needs to be captured. Non-capturing lambdas use singleton `Function` instances instead.

With `inline` modifier applied to the higher-order function the compiled call looks much better:

```
int mod = 2;
int it = 1337;
if (it % mod == 0) {
   ;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your  answer.  It was  really  clear  for me.